# Gtk2Hs: onEntryActivate deprecated

Tags: haskell, gtk, deprecated, gtk2hs

[The documantation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk-0.12.5.6/docs/Graphics-UI-Gtk-Entry-Entry.html) about entries in Gtk2Hs has the entry about the Event `onEntryActivate`, which is triggered when the user presses enter within the entry field. This seems like something you want for most of your entries. So why is this in the Deprecated section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that these "special" events are all deprecated and instead the generic `on`funcion should be used. In this case the it would be `on yourEntry entryActivate doSomething`.